# Replacing characters at the start and end of a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose this string:

```
b*any string here*
```

In case this exists, I want to replace b* at the beginning to `<b>`, and the * at the end to `</b>` (Disregard the backslash I need it for escaping on SO site).

Moreover, there might be more then one match:

```
b*any string here* and after that b*string b*.
```

These cases should not be handled:

```
b*foo bar
foo bar*
bb*foo bar* (b is not after a whitespace or beginning of string).
```

I've gotten this far:

```
(?<=b\*)(.*?)(?=\*)
```

This gives me the string in between but Im having difficulties in doing the swap.

Comment: "*Disregard the backslash I need it for escaping on SO site*" - no, you don't. Wrap whatever you want to display as code in back-tick characters: `\`your html entities/code here\`` to show it as code.

Comment: The lookarounds are non-consuming, use "regular", non-consuming pattern: `/\bb\*(.*?)\*/g` and replace with `<b>$1</b>`. Or, if you really after a whitespace boundary, `.replace(/(^|\s)b\*(.*?)\*/g, "$1<b>$2</b>")`

Comment: Sorry, I meant *"regular", consuming pattern*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you only need to capture the text you want to preserve:

```
var result = theString.replace(/\bb\*(.*?)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

The `\b` at the begining of the regex means word boundary so that it only matches `b`s that are not part of a word. `$1` means the first captured group `(.*?)`.

**Example:**

```js
var str1 = "b*any string here* and after that b*string b*.";

var str2 = `b*foo bar
foo bar*
bb*foo bar* (b is not after a whitespace or beginning of string).`;

console.log(str1.replace(/\bb\*(.*?)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>"));

console.log(str2.replace(/\bb\*(.*?)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>"));
```

Comment: It sure isn't me that downvoted. str1 excellent. But why does str2 not work even if I put a whitespace after the second line(foo bar *)?

Comment: @ddy250 I've just tested it and it works. Are you sure? `... b b*text*` works as expected.

Comment: Maybe it's just the environment I tested it at. Anyway it's a corner I don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\b(?:b\*)(.+?)(?:\*)`, so

```
const result = yourString.replace(/\b(?:b\*)(.+?)(?:\*)/, "<b>$1</b>");
```

See the 'Replace' tab https://regexr.com/447cq